# YUM won't update KERNEL

Tags: kernel, yum, upgrade

```
...
...
...    
--> Running transaction check
    ---> Package db4-devel.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.el6_4 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: db4-cxx = 4.7.25-18.el6_4 for package: db4-devel-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libdb_cxx-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: db4-devel-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
    ---> Package gdbm-devel.x86_64 0:1.8.0-36.el6 will be installed
    ---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 for package: kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
    Package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.noarch is obsoleted by vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab083.2.noarch which is already installed
    ---> Package lzo.x86_64 0:2.03-3.1.el6 will be installed
    ---> Package mesa-private-llvm.x86_64 0:3.3-0.3.rc3.el6 will be installed
    ---> Package p11-kit.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.el6_5.2 will be installed
    ---> Package p11-kit-trust.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.el6_5.2 will be installed
    ---> Package shared-mime-info.x86_64 0:0.70-4.el6 will be installed
    ---> Package snappy.x86_64 0:1.1.0-1.el6 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package db4-cxx.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.el6_4 will be installed
    ---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 for package: kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
    Package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.noarch is obsoleted by vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab083.2.noarch which is already installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    Error: Package: kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 (updates)
               Requires: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6
               Removing: vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab083.2.noarch (@openvz-kernel-rhel6)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6
               Updated By: vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab090.5.noarch (openvz-kernel-rhel6)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch (base)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6
               Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.noarch (updates)
                   kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest


    uname -a
    Linux LOD1.downtownhost.com 2.6.32-042stab083.2 #1 SMP Fri Nov 8 18:08:40 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to get the kernel to stab090.5 to avoid some exploits but I don't get why YUM is broken.

Do I have too many kernels in under /boot/grub?

EDIT:

I see the following

```
yum list kernel.*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dattobackup.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * openvz-kernel-rhel6: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * openvz-utils: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * soluslabs: mirror.us1.soluslabs.net
 * updates: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-279.el6                                              @anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-358.0.1.el6                                          @updates
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-358.14.1.el6                                         @updates
kernel.x86_64                                        2.6.32-358.23.2.el6                                         @updates
```

However I don't see the OpenVZ kernel.

Now if I do this:

```
yum remove kernel kernel-firmware
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-279.el6 will be erased
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.0.1.el6 will be erased
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.14.1.el6 will be erased
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.23.2.el6 will be erased
---> Package vzkernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-042stab083.2 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                  Version                            Repository                                               Size
=========================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 kernel                           x86_64                2.6.32-279.el6                     @anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3                114 M
 kernel                           x86_64                2.6.32-358.0.1.el6                 @updates                                                116 M
 kernel                           x86_64                2.6.32-358.14.1.el6                @updates                                                116 M
 kernel                           x86_64                2.6.32-358.23.2.el6                @updates                                                116 M
 vzkernel-firmware                noarch                2.6.32-042stab083.2                @openvz-kernel-rhel6                                     19 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================================================================
Remove        5 Package(s)

Installed size: 480 M
Is this ok [y/N]: n
```

How do I exclude the openvz kernel?

Comment: What type of host is this, you're using the vz packages which would seem to indicate that this is an OpenVZ guest or host system. Is that the case?

Comment: Hey, this is the HOST system. I ran a "yum update" expecting the typical download and y to install. CentOS 6.4 I think as well.

Comment: You've definitely got some issues with the installs of kernels and the dependent packages. I would work through the dependencies of the kernel you're actually using and remove everything else.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I remove the kernels from /boot?

Comment: You use `yum` to remove them. `yum remove ....`. I would find an old one that you're sure you're not using and remove it to start. Keep removing them 1 at a time until you've got most/all of them removed, then attempt your `yum update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to remove vzkernel-firmware package:

> ## rpm -e vzkernel-firmware

and exclude it by adding the line marked in bold to openvz yum repo file **/etc/yum.repos.d/openvz.repo:**

```
[openvz-kernel-rhel6]
name=OpenVZ RHEL6-based kernel
#baseurl=http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/current/
mirrorlist=http://download.openvz.org/kernel/mirrors-rhel6-2.6.32
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.openvz.org/RPM-GPG-Key-OpenVZ
exclude=vzkernel-firmware
```